# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: I am using laravel(backend) and yeoman angular generator(front end)

Tags: laravel-5, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/angular/blog/public/index.php/api/v1/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost/angular/blog/public/index.php/api/v1/login","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}

I m getting this errors when trying to send data from yeoman angular(frontend) and laravel(backend).

Comment: add more details in your question like what plugin you are using for CORS. You can get CORS headers enabled using https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors . if you use that on this route this error should go away

Comment: i trid tht..but getting different error

Comment: http://localhost/angular/blog/public/index.php/api/v1/login [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 15ms]
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost/angular/blog/public/index.php/api/v1/login","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}  angular.js:14516:18

Comment: thanks sir....its working now